# ios: waiting for method to finish executing before continuing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to IOS development and am currently facing a problem.

When method A is called, it calls method B and then it wait for delegate `connectionDidFinish` which `connectionDidFinish` will execute MethodC.

My question is how do I ensure that methodA to methodC has finished executing before executing NSLog?

I found that a way to solve this problem is to use notification center. Send notification to me after finishing executing methodC. I don't think this is a good solution. Is there another way to do this?

Example:

```
 [a methodA];
 NSLog(@"FINISH");
```

Comment: Please read observer pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 9):

If any of those methods perform actions asynchronously, you can't. You'll have to look into a different way of doing this. I personally try to use completion blocks when ever I can, although it's perfectly fine to do this other ways, like with delegate methods. Here's a basic example using a completion block.

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    [self methodAWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
        // check if thing worked.
    }];
}

- (void)methodAWithCompletion:(void (^) (BOOL success))completion
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, kNilOptions), ^{

        // go do something asynchronous...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            completion(ifThingWorked)

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Can you explain why we have to use dispatch_async twice?
can I just call completion(ifThingWorked)
Thanks

Comment: @ElizaS The first one moves the code execution to a background thread, where you can perform blocking operations. The second returns to the main thread so you can do things like update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, methodA **must** finish executing before the log statement will execute.

However, if methodA starts an asynchronous process that takes a while to finish and returns before it is finished, then you need to do something different. Usually you don't want to freeze the user interface while you are waiting, so you set up a delegate, pass in a completion block, or wait for an "ok, I'm done" notification.

All those are very valid, good ways to solve the problem of waiting for asynchronous tasks to finish running.

Newer APIs are starting to use completion blocks. Examples are:

- presentViewController:animated:completion:, which takes a completion
  block that gets called once the new view controller is fully
  on-screen and "ready for business.
- animateWithDuration:animations:completion:, which takes a completion
  block that gets executed once the animation is finished, and
- sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:, which starts an
  asynchronous URL request (usually an HTTP GET or PUT request) and
  provides a completion block that gets called once the request has
  been completed (or fails)