# iOS determine when NSMutableArray sortUsingComparator is complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I am sorting a mutable array as follows:

```
[m_maFoundObjects sortUsingComparator:
 ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
     FADObject * o1 = (FADObject *)obj1;
     FADObject * o2 = (FADObject *)obj2;
     return [o1.name compare:o2.name];
 }
 ];
```

Can someone tell me the best way to determine when the sort is done so I can call reloadData on my list?

Comment: You can use 2 methods for to check for to execute your reload data after to complete the first method There are a lot of examples in stackoverflow like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20779096/921789) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16472235/921789)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting is done synchronously, so you should be able to reload in the next statement.

```
[m_maFoundObjects sortUsingComparator:
 ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
     FADObject * o1 = (FADObject *)obj1;
     FADObject * o2 = (FADObject *)obj2;
     return [o1.name compare:o2.name];
 }
 ];

// Here you can reload your data
```

Comment: Hmm, actually that is what I thought as I have sorted this way before.  However, in this case it was not working.  I must have other issues in the code.  Thanks for the clarification/sanity check!!!!

Comment: Yes, it was my fault… too early, not enough coffee… turn out I was sorting the wrong list.  Thanks for the help, sometimes you just need someone to explain it to.

Comment: No problem, I understand the coffee issue ;) If you have more issues within the scope of this question, let me know and I will help. Otherwise remember to accept the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, all the array sorting methods operate synchronously, even `sortWithOptions:usingComparator:` with an options value of NSSortConcurrent.

The docs are silent on this point, but I just tested and confirmed. I wrote a test comparator block that logged the time and thread id, and logged the time before and after the sort. With a large enough array I as able to see the comparator block firing concurrently from different threads, but the sort method did not return until the sort process was complete.

I just posted the following documentation comment:

> The documentation for the method sortWithOptions:usingComparator: is
>   incomplete.
>
> This method always operates synchronously, even when you specify an
>   opts value of NSSortConcurrent.
>
> Put in plain english: 'This method does not return until the array is
>   sorted, even if you specify sort options of NSSortConcurrent". In that
>   case the comparator blocks may be invoked on background threads, but
>   the method waits until the sort is complete before returning control
>   to the caller.

Let's all send in feedback on this issue, since Apple is more likely to fix something if they receive multiple reports about it.